# Sheafification of singular cochains

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

Let $S^k$ be the presheaf on a space $X$ that assigns to every open set $U$ the abelian group $S^k(U)$ of singular k- cochains on $U$. This is clearly not a sheaf. Consider the sheafification $F^k$ of each $S^k$. These sheaves form an exact resolution of the constant sheaf of integers.

We can take global sections on this sheaf resolution to obtain a cochain complex $F^*(X)$. Does the cohomology of this cochain complex coincides with ordinary singular cohomology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said this explicitly, but your claim is that the sheaf cohomology of the constant sheaf $\Bbb Z_X$ is isomorphic to the singular cohomology of $X$:
$$H^\ast(X, \Bbb Z_X) \cong H^\ast_{\text{sing}}(X; \Bbb Z).$$
This is true for $X$ locally contractible. One checks that the complexes $S^\ast(X)$ and $\Gamma(X, S^\ast(X))$ are quasi-isomorphic. More generally, the assertion holds for any abelian group $G$:
$$H^\ast(X, G_X) \cong H^\ast_{\text{sing}}(X; G)$$
when $X$ is locally contractible.

I don't have any references on hand, but I would expect that you could find the proof in most books that introduce the concept of sheaf cohomology.

Comment: I just found a proof here http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/sheaves_coh.pdf thank you!

Comment: Is there an example that the sheaf cohomology is not isomorphic to the singular cohomology when $X$ is not locally contractible?

Comment: @YuchenLiu I do not know of any specific counterexample.